# ksoap2 for android capitalization throwing an exception

Tags: android, xml, ksoap2

I am trying to use ksoap2, but it appears that capitalizing the name of the soap object throws an exception. The code sample and the exception it throws is below.

The odd thing is that when I examine `ht.responseDump`, the data does come back from the server

Thanks in advance!

```
SoapObject foo = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE1, "foo");
SoapObject bar = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE1, "bar");
SoapObject search = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE1, "search");
SoapObject keywords = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE2, "Keywords"); //spelling this at 'keywords' is fine

search.addSoapObject(keywords);
bar.addSoapObject(search);
foo.addSoapObject(bar);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.bodyOut = foo ;
envelope.setAddAdornments(false);

HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE("http://foo.bar/service");
ht.debug = true;
ht.call(null, envelope);
//returns the correct data, but throws an XmlPullParserException exception
//unexpected type (position:TEXT
//https://www.trus...@1:1327 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44eddd48)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe it's because you are not receiving the response (call the getResponse method).